# p value for the test statistic in python using rtool

Tags: r, python

I have the following data,

```
These are the x and y values to find correlation 
x=115778,171235,1
y_a=31920,49327,0
y_b=83858,121908,1
cor_a= 0.99947573036   // These are the correlation values using numpy (x,y_a)
cor_b= 0.999915675755   // (x,y_b)
test_statistic_a= 30.870014264  // test statistic value using formula
test_statistic_b= 76.9983294567
d_f=1  // degrees of freedom
```

How to find the p_value for the above data and test the hypothesis? using rpy2

Comment: Could you indicate: (1) what your test statistic is, and (2) what hypothesis test you are interested in. I anticipate you want to test the null hypothesis of zero correlation (of $x$ with $y_a$ and $y_b$), but in that case your test statistics and DF look quite strange.

Comment: @chl my test statistic is t = R * sqrt( ( N - 2 ) / ( 1 - R**2 ) )

Comment: If you use rpy2, why not calling R `cor.test()` function? For $(x, y_a)$, I found $p = 0.02062$. Otherwise, you have to look up for a Student t distribution with one df and the corresponding quantile (`2*(1-pt(30.87, 1))` with R). Now, I leave up to you to decide whether such a test makes really sense with only three data points.

Comment: Done, btw as this is merely about Python/R coding issue this is not really suitable for Cross Validated. However, it sounds like you can no longer post questions on SO, so I'm just closing this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the R code, for reference:

```
> x <- c(115778,171235,1)
> ya <- c(31920,49327,0)
> yb <- c(83858,121908,1)
> cor(x, ya)
[1] 0.9994757
> cor(x, yb)
[1] 0.9999157
> cor.test(x, ya)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x and ya
t = 30.87, df = 1, p-value = 0.02062
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      cor
0.9994757
```

With Python, you can use the following (I assume you have a working [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/index.html)), and directly use IPython `%paste` if you like:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robj
x = robj.IntVector([115778,171235,1])
ya = robj.IntVector([31920,49327,0])
yb = robj.IntVector([83858,121908,1])
cor_test = robj.r['cor.test']
res = cor_test(x, ya)
print(res.r_repr()) # R way
res[2] # python way
```